# Does OneNote not support Sticky Notes on Mac?

Tags: mac, microsoft-onenote

I noticed recently that OneNote on my Android phone has gained support for something called Sticky Notes. I find them pretty useful *but* when I open OneNote on my Mac, I cannot see them. I believe I'm running the latest version.

A feature that's only available on one platform isn't so good - can anyone confirm if it is supported?

Comment: To my knowledge, Sticky Notes isn't a OneNote feature, it's an separate application that runs on the device.  Sticky Notes only runs on Windows, Android, and iOS.

Comment: It's definitely provided via ON on Android. At the bottom of the app-screen you see "notebooks" and "Stick Notes" as the two main options

Comment: It's a feature of Android due to the integration between Sticky Notes on Android and OneNote on Android.  If you did not have Sticky Notes installed you would not have that integration.

Comment: @Ramhound nope. As I already said I have never heard of this application. I just checked and I do not have that application on my phone! I assume it's part of MS' cloud-y suite so perhaps I have it via OneDrive or something.

Comment: If you have a OneDrive account, it means you have a Microsoft account, which means if you use Sticky Notes on any platform your Sticky Notes are synched between the supported platforms.  All I know is that Sticky Notes is it's own application on Android, iOS, and Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A feature that's only available on one platform isn't so good - can anyone confirm if it is supported?

Sticky Notes is a separate application that runs on Windows.  Sticky Notes on iOS and Android is integrated into OneNote on those respective platforms.  There currently is NOT a Sticky Notes application that supports macOS.

> Microsoft Sticky Notes is ready to hit the road with a bit of OneNote integration on Android and iOS.

Source:

- [Microsoft Sticky Notes are coming to OneNote on iOS and Android](https://www.windowscentral.com/microsoft-sticky-notes-are-coming-onenote-ios-and-android)
- [Get started with Sticky Notes](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/get-started-with-sticky-notes-86b36182-fdf5-4f9b-af7a-2846f83263f5)

Comment: OK, I think that's cleared up. A bit odd I've never installed/heard of Sticky Notes so it's _only_ used via ON in my case.

Answer (score 3):

If you have Microsoft e-mail account linked to your Android One Note app, just go to the settings on your Mac, then go to the accounts, find your microsoft email (or add one), and enable notes. You'll se your quick notes (or sticky notes) from the Android One Note app in the native Apple notetaking app.

Answer (score 1):

If you have your Microsoft account setup in System Preferences > Internet Accounts, you can access Sticky Notes via Apple Notes app.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

There is a kind of support in MacOS today, even though it is via the Browser in the end.  You access it from your native Microsoft Outlook application

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just add your MS account to the Macos internet account,the key is sign the ms account as a Exchange,so you can see you can sync the mail and notes,etc.then you can check your sticky notes from the Notes app.

Answer (score -1):

Sticky Notes is apart of Microsoft Outlook,
https://www.guidingtech.com/access-sticky-notes-iphone-android-mac/

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.